hide elements according to index position using jquery
I have a dynamic table with many columns and rows. In some cells there is specific value "N/A".
I want to hide cells containing "N/A" along with its table header too
How is it possible using jquery

I tried this code and it works partially. Table cells were hidden perfectly but only first table header "material" is hidden.
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var findna = jQuery('tr').find('td:contains(N/A)').index();
  jQuery('tr').find('td:contains(N/A)').css('display', 'none');
  jQuery('table tr:first-child')
    .find("th:eq(" + findna + ")").css('display', 'none');

  console.log(findna)
});


in all rows those 3 columns value is N/A

Protips: Use jQuery(function($) { on your first line (shorthand and alias) and you can use $ safely inside that function instead of jQuery. Also, use const for storing index rather than var, and give it a semantic name like naIndex, which should describe the value and not your means of getting it.

You need to update your code to get all 3 indexes and then hide
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('tr').find('td:contains(N/A)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
  jQuery('tr:nth-child(2)').find('td:contains(N/A)').each(function() {
    jQuery('table tr:first-child').find("th:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").css('display', 'none');
  });
});



jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('tr').find('td:contains(N/A)').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
  });
  jQuery('tr:nth-child(2)').find('td:contains(N/A)').each(function() {
    jQuery('table tr:first-child').find("th:eq(" + $(this).index() + ")").css('display', 'none');
  });
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Type</th>
    <th>Material</th>
    <th>Core</th>
    <th>Wire</th>
    <th>Vendor rate</th>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>switch</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>30</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>switch</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>N/A</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
</table>



